# My Cat Palm is yellowing then browning :(( help!

Tags: houseplants, diagnosis, palm

I purchased this cat palm about a month ago from someone in town. They had cats and dogs and felt the palm was getting a lot of rowdiness from the the pets, so they gifted it to me. We named him “Kevin” so I will refer to that name in regards to the palm. Kevin was green and looked good but had some scratches on the leave from the cats....

After I took him home I placed him in a corner about 17 far across a window that brings the sunset in. (You can imagine the lighting conditions) we read that we have to water him daily?? So we gave him about 4 cups of water for the first 2 days and saw a huge change. He began to turn yellow. So we then took a break from watering him about a week and noticed browning. Someone please help. I really don’t want Kevin to die on me. We have aloe Vera plants and bamboo but nothing like this. I have no experience whatsoever!!! Thank you guys.[image]